# javascript add day to date?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string startDate, and I am trying to convert it to a date obj so I can add a day to it and get a new string "2020-09-16"

My code below is not working though:

```
  let startDate = "2020-09-15"
  let startDateObj = Date.parse(startDate)
  console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj)
  startDateObj.setDate(startDateObj.getDate()+1);
  console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj)
```

produces output:

```
startDateObj =  1600128000000
(node:517) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: startDateObj.getDate is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one day to date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312296/add-one-day-to-date-in-javascript)

Comment: "The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31)." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead off `Date.parse(starDate)`, you'll need to create a new date: `= new Date(startDate)`

```js
let startDate = "2020-09-15"
let startDateObj = new Date(startDate)
console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj)
startDateObj.setDate(startDateObj.getDate()+1);
console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj)
```

---

Based on comments, formatted to `yyyy-mm-dd`
For more info, please check [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

```js
let startDate = "2020-09-15"
let startDateObj = new Date(startDate)

console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
startDateObj.setDate(startDateObj.getDate()+1);
console.log('startDateObj = ', startDateObj.toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

[JS Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: my output comes out to `2020-09-15T00:00:00.000Z`, if i use startDateObj.toString() it becomes Tue Sep 15 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), how can i get the string as `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

Comment: @Martin Please see my edited answer! Hope it helps!